# Compare two strings with dash issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

From the T-SQL code below you can see that dash `-` on the 3rd place of a `nvarchar` string does not equal dash on 3rd place of a `varchar` string.

```
if substring(N'BV‐D',3,1) <> substring('BV‐D',3,1)
    select substring(N'BV‐D',3,1) as nchar
            , substring('BV‐D',3,1) as char
            , ASCII(substring(N'BV‐D',3,1)) as ncode
            , ASCII(substring('BV‐D',3,1)) as code
            , 'Non-Equal' as status
```

output:

| nchar | char | ncode | code | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ‐ | - | 45 | 45 | Non-Equal |

If I will retype '-' or add N, or remove N in both cases strings will become equal. ASCII code is 45 in both cases.

Why are they not equal?

Initially it was not typed manually, but copied from different sources.

Comment: You're comparing Unicode and ASCII strings. The query doesn't really demonstrate anything.

Comment: For me it demonstrates a lot. I'm comparing values from different tables to find difference, and this string does not equal. The only one inequality within 100000 of rows. Dash '-' is used in many names, but only in one case it seems to be different dashes.

Comment: No it doesn't. You use the wrong functions which means you're comparing the wrong numbers. Try `select UNICODE(N'‐'),ASCII('‐')` instead using *the question's* characters. That's not the dash you assumed it was

Comment: The query contains Unicode dashes, not minus signs. There's no such character in the ASCII range so `ASCII()` maps the dash to the minus character. If you use `UNICODE` you'll see what the actual character code is

Comment: No I see what is going on. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Because they *aren't* equal. You have a string which contains non-ASCII charcters that you're putting into a `varchar` and then (implicitly) converting that value back to an `nvarchar`. By that point it's too late and information has been lost.

Let's look at these values from a `varbinary` perspective:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(varbinary(10),N'BV‐D') AS NvarcharBinary,
       CONVERT(varbinary(10),'BV‐D') AS VarcharBinary,
       CONVERT(varbinary(10),CONVERT(nvarchar(5),'BV‐D')) AS VarcharNvarcharBinary;
```

This gives the results:

| NvarcharBinary | VarcharBinary | VarcharNvarcharBinary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0x4200560010204400 | 0x42562D44 | 0x420056002D004400 |

Notice the third character for the first string has the representation `0x1020`. Such a character **cannot** be represented in a `varchar`, and when you attempt to store it in one it is implicitly converted to a similar character, `0x2D`. Then when you convert that *back* to an `nvarchar` you get `0x2D00`. (*Note, not all characters are converted to similar characters. Those that aren't are replaced with `?`.*)

Unsurprisingly, `0x2D00` and `0x1020` are *not* the same, and so the strings are not equal.

Comment: Thom A, thanks a lot for your post. Let me notice, that I do not lose nothing on a happy occasion. String with N it's string that contains NCHAR(8208) character, and string without N use NVAR(45) inside. I've copied it from different sources.

Comment: That is *not* what your question demonstrates, @fapw . You have `if substring(N'BV‐D',3,1) <> substring('BV‐D',3,1)` and *both* of those strings are using a [Hyphen character](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2010).

Comment: *"that I do not lose nothing on a happy occasion* Intentional double negative? So you do lose something? Yes, you're correct, you do.

Comment: Yes, double checked. You are right, lose. I've copied the same string with Hyphen character in left and right sides of expression. Thanks for noticing it.

Answer (score 2):

That's not the dash you assume it is, it's a different Unicode character. The query is using the wrong function though, `ASCII`, which does *not* return the actual Unicode code.

If you try

```
select UNICODE(N'‐') as Hyphen,
       UNICODE(N'-') as Minus,
       ASCII('‐') As Ascii_Dash,
       ASCII(N'-') as Ascii_Minus
```

You'll get

```
Hyphen  Minus   Ascii_Dash  Ascii_Minus
8208    45      45          45
```

8208 is the [Hyphen character](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2010). That's the character generated by eg HTML's `&dash;`, used to separate words and syllable's. It's not the same as the [minus](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+002D) character on our keyboards.

There are a *lot* of dash characters used in typography and hence Unicode. Full width, half width, breaking or non-breaking etc.

**Fixing this**

You can use [TRANSLATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to map individual characters :

```
select translate(N'BV‐D', N'‐', N'-')
```

This trick is used in SQL Server to [normalize equivalent Unicode characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811976/normalize-unicode-string-in-sql-server) because T-SQL doesn't have a NORMALIZE function. This wouldn't help here anyway, because HYPHEN-MINUS and HYPHEN aren't considered equivalent. You'd have to add all possible options though, as the example in the linked question shows :

```
select translate(last_name, 'éêëèàäçïîìôöòûù', 'eeeeaaciiiooouu') from employees
```

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos, thanks a lot for your answer, not it's clear for me.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002D/index.htm) is the ASCII-45 HYPHEN-MINUS. May I comment that this is the more common hyphen. It's what appears if I press the hyphen key in my US keyboard.

[This](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2010/index.htm) is the Unicode-8208 HYPHEN, well beyong the ASCII Range. It is what your 'BV‐D' string contains. If you don't use a unicode string with `N`, sql server converts it to the similar ASCII-45 character. Still, they differ, and that's the reason you get an inequality.