# UTF-8 and os.listdir()

Tags: python, linux, macos, utf-8

I'm having a bit of trouble with a file containing the "ș" character (that's `\xC8\x99` in UTF-8 - LATIN SMALL LETTER S WITH COMMA BELOW).

I'm creating a `ș.txt` file and trying to get it back with `os.listdir()`. Unfortunately, `os.listdir()` returns it back as `s\xCC\xA6` ("s" + COMBINING COMMA BELOW) and my test program (below) fails.

This happens on my OS X, but it works on a Linux machine. Any idea what exactly causes this behavior (both environments are configured with LANG=en_US.UTF8) ?

Here's the test program:

```
#coding: utf-8
import os

fname = "ș.txt"
with open(fname, "w") as f:
    f.write("hi")

files = os.listdir(".")
print "fname: ", fname
print "files: ", files

if fname in files:
    print "found"
else:
    print "not found"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [OS X filesystem mostly uses *decomposed* characters](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1173/_index.html) rather than their combined form. You'll need to normalise the filenames back to the NFC combined normalised form:

```
import unicodedata
files = [unicodedata.normalize('NFC', f) for f in os.listdir(u'.')]
```

This processes filenames *as unicode*; you'd otherwise need to decode the bytestring to unicode first.

Also see the [`unicodedata.normalize()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I understand what's going on now. Your code is not working btw, I need to do `u"ș.txt" in [unicodedate.normalize('NFC', f) for f in os.listdir(u'.')]` instead.

Comment: @Unknown: right, or decode and again encode. But using a unicode path is better.

Comment: @Unknown how can you do that? I'm facing with that problem tooo

Comment: @NamPham: do what exactly, what problem are you facing? The `files` list will contain a list of Unicode string objects, each normalised.

Comment: I'm faceing about decoding and encoding process, I can't put `u'.'` as an argument for listdir. My path is unicode :(

Comment: @NamPham: all you need is a `unicode` object. If your variable is a `str` object, you'll first need to decode.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you.

Comment: Would the same go for Windows 10?

Comment: @Superdooperhero no. Windows does not perform any normalisation on pathnames. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041013/unicode-normalization-in-windows.