# Python encoding issue?

Tags: python

I need to test if a certain string (for example 'võiks') equals the name of any of the files contained in a directory.

```
>>>words = [ f.replace('.html', '') for f in listdir('lemma_pages/test') if isfile(join('lemma_pages/test',f)) ]

>>>words
['võibolla', 'võid', 'võiks', 'võimalik', 'võin', 'võta', 'võtan', 'võtta']

>>>'võiks' in words
False
```

But when I test for it, I get False when I expected otherwise. I am opening the file containing the words in this way:

```
open('et_500.txt', 'rt', encoding="utf-8")
```

Any idea of what I am not doing right ?

Comment: What platform are you on? If this is on Mac, see [UTF-8 and os.listdir()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26732985)

Comment: whats the result of `sys.getdefaultencoding()` in your terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data may not be normalized. Before comparing the strings, normalize with:

```
data = unicodedata.normalize('NFC', data)
```

To provide some more details, `õ` could be [U+00F5 (LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH TILDE)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f5/index.htm) or it could be [U+0062 (LATIN SMALL LETTER B)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0062/index.htm) followed by [U+0303 (COMBINING TILDE)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0303/index.htm). Normalizing is necessary so that no matter which flavor you get, they will compare identically.